# Given seven points inside a hexagon with side length $1$ prove that there exists two points with distance at most $1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, pigeonhole-principle

Seven points are given inside a regular hexagon whose sides have length $1$. Prove that there are two among these seven points such that the distance between them is at most $1$.

Now if I divide the hexagon into $6$ regions, since we have $7$ points, by the pigeon hole principle there is a region with at least two points in it. The distance between two points is at most $1$ because each region is an equilateral triangle with sides of length $1$.

Would this be sufficient or any other approaches that would work better.

Comment: You can't do better! Your approach is as good as it gets for this problem. Nice going!

Comment: I will add that answer to this question also shows a picture: [Pigeonhole principle, choosing point in a region](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1283267).

Answer (score 5):

This seems sufficient, but you can add something like this:

The distance between two points in an equilateral triangle with side length $1$ is at most $1$ because this triangle lies in a circle of radius $1/2$.

Comment: Over the top! Enclosing the equilateral triangle in circle of radius $1$ is easier and is all you need.

Comment: @ThePortakal: Good point! (+1). While it might seem _obvious_ that two points in an equilateral triangle can't be more than a distance of $1$ from each other, it does require proof.

Comment: @Rob Arthan: Why is radius $1$ sufficient?

Comment: @quasi: Because the equilateral triangle is contained in the circle of radius $1$ about any of its points.

Comment: @Rob Arthan: That seems circular to me. How do you know that? An in any case, that's not just one circle.

Comment: No: if $X$ is any point in the equilateral triangle, and $U_1$, $U_2$ and $U_3$ are its vertices, then the triangles $XU_iU_j$ ($i\neq j$) all have $U_iU_j$ as their longest side. But let's not worry about it too much. ThePortakal's answer is fine as it stands.

Comment: @Rob Arthan: Maybe that works, but frankly, the single enclosing circle -- the circumscribed circle with radius $\sqrt{3}/6$ (hence less than $1/2$) is more instantly clear.

Comment: The maximum distance between two points in any triangle is its longest side-length.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown: It's a question of what's known, and what requires proof (at a given level).

Comment: My point was that you don't need to estimate the radius of the circumcircle.

Comment: Ok, I get your points (both yours and Lord Shark's), but I felt ThePortakal's argument defended nicely against any possible doubts.

Comment: Umm, my calculation of the radius of the circumcircle is $R = \frac{1}{2} \frac{a}{\sin A} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} > \frac{1}{2}$.  In any case, the diameter has to be longer than the side 1 (it's the hypotenuse of a right triangle with one of its legs being 1).

Comment: @Daniel Schepler: Oops, you're right. So the circumcircle doesn't work. Back to Lord Shark's argument then. Of course, unless that's considered known, it still requires proof.

Answer (score 2):

It can be seen that the constant 1 cannot be improved, by the example of 6 vertices of the hexagon and the center. However, the number 7 can be reduced to 6, as following : given 6 points inside a disk of radius 1, there exist two of them at a distance at most 1. If one of them is the center, it's clear. Ohterwise, join the points with the center. There exist two of these radiuses that form an angle at most 60. Hence the points lie in a circular sector of angle 60, so the distance between them is at most the radius, 1.